# Using TABLOCK with merge SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, deadlock

I have a merge query similar to the one below:

```
MERGE [Unshipped] u
USING [Order] or ON or.ID = u.ID

WHEN MATCHED AND u.Date <> or.Date
   THEN
      UPDATE 
      SET u.Date = or.Date

WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN 
       INSERT (ID, FK, Date)
       VALUES (or.ID, or.FK, or.Date)
```

If i am to add TABLOCK where is the best place for it? I would have assumed i would put it like below - wrap the whole merge statement:

```
     MERGE [Unshipped] u WITH (TABLOCK)
     USING [Order] order or ON or.ID = u.ID
```

or is it more suitable for it to go with the insert statement?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve by using tablock?  Also you should read this article on merge issues: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/  In spite of its convenience, there are a number of gotchas.  I've resorted to WITH (SERIALIZABLE) or just replacing it with INSERT/UPDATE combination

Comment: @user1443098 deadlock

Comment: There was an issue raised with MS for that which was closed as "by design"

Answer (score 1):

You only need:

```
 MERGE [Unshipped] WITH (TABLOCK) AS u 
 USING [Order] or ON or.ID = u.ID
```

Rest of the MERGE statement is unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st question that you should ask yourself is why do you need this table hint at all?
Merge is a DML statement with runs in an implicit transaction.
In that way, you'll block the entire table, but if you'd like to do you should put your hint on the table that you **NEED** to lock. 
Just have a look at the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
MERGE [Unshipped] u WITH (TABLOCK)

USING [Order] order as or WITH (TABLOCK) ON or.ID = u.ID
```

It really depends which table you want to lock Unshipped or Order.

Comment: Unfortunately, MERGE is not truly, fully atomic

Comment: It really depends on which version of the SQL server and about which issue are we talking here (Merge is really buggy) :)

Comment: Exactly, that's why I shy away from it.